# Что означает запись в error log?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, apache2

Всем привет! Отлавливаю ошибку wordpress + ubuntu 16.04 , apache2. Лег сайт. Смотрю логи:

в аксес по времени отру:

> 212.90.166.2 - - [25/Jul/2018:13:47:03 +0300] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2017/01/768x130_generator_2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 32386 "http://matari.ua/generators.html?swoof=1&pa_obem-resivera-l=50-100" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.95.67.50.242 - - [25/Jul/2018:14:08:00 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 601 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"

и error log ( не могу понять , что значит этот кусок ( по времени подходит ) ):

> [Wed Jul 25 13:46:55.437099 2018] [:error] [pid 4054] [client 212.90.166.2:61323] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_deregister_javascript' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 524, referer: http://matari.ua/kompressory.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwv-DaBRCcARIsAI9sba_o5Qj_2-JzJyOB8wRwFMsLOEj5VLD7APp9O0s0OKTv44ntaQIYCzkaAt83EALw_wcB

в конце много <0x00> , sublime не дает скопировать.

Comment: "function 'my_deregister_javascript' not found or invalid function name" по-моему все понятно. Функция с таким именем скорее всего не объявлена. Или не подключен файл с ней.

Comment: 1) Возможно у вас стоит плагин который работает с другим плагином или не докачаный плагин или плагин работает с конкретной темой. 2) Или вы использовали хук с какого то сайта и просто вставили его не глядя... Я всё же склоняюсь ко второму варианту

Comment: @walfter  Тема самописная  , Второй вариант отпадает . Стоит не мало плагинов , как самописных так и установленных . Перебирать все плагины ?

Comment: @IlyaSidorychev вы ничего не копировали? Обычно это бывает в хуках. Можете попробовать отключить файл functions.php просто закомментировав код, если ошибка продолжится перебирайте плагины

Comment: Не туда смотрите. `http://matari.ua/generators.html?swoof=1&pa_obem-resivera-l=50-100` сейчас работает, ошибки нет. Ваша выдача из error_log - это всего лишь Warning, сайт от этого не упадёт. Ищите в логах fatal.

Comment: @KAGGDesing Да , я его поднял ... Но все же решил разобраться в чем была проблема так как лег сайт именно в это время , дальше в логах пусто до того момента как я его снова завел .

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо !